# Eclipse: The global variable is not explicitly declared

Tags: javascript, global-variables, warnings

I have a javascript variable that in eclipse is giving me the following warning : 
**The global variable index is not explicitly declared.**

```
var inputs, index, inputLenght;
inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
inputLength =inputs.length;
for (index = 0; index < inputLength; ++index) {
   // some stuf to do 
}
```

When I do this  the warning is gone

```
 for (var index = 0; index < inputLength; ++index) {
    // some stuf to do 
 }
```

I want to understand why defining it as a global variable gives a warning?

Comment: It's the `var` before the variable name `index`. Eclipse is saying that is not explicitly declared, it's a good behavior to declare variables with `var` before using them. JavaScript will however create the variable when you use it, but that would, for example, create problem when you misstype `indxe`, because it will not complain but just create a new variable with that name and behave oddly

Comment: In Webstorm I don't get any warnings. Must be just an Eclipse thing

Comment: Exlipse means that you don't initialize variable, it's just a warning about code style. BTW, you have typo inputLeng**ht**/inputLeng**th**

Comment: but isn't it better to declare the variable outside the for loop performance wise ?

Comment: `inputs` must be declared outside of course; length predefine is "microoptimization". Index is better to define in for cycle section which designed for it.

Comment: @user2515601 variables declared in the condition of a loop are outside the loop. Also agree about the micro-optimisation point. Unless you're working on drivers or ray tracing I'd save your time for other things.

Comment: You've declared `index` in a very decent way at the first line of your code, but somehow Eclipse can't see it, or is just guiding you towards a certain coding style (though I'd prefer your style).

Answer (score 0):

Because in your first example you are declaring it with no value, but in the second you declare it *with* a value -

```
var index;
```

vs

```
var index = 0;
```

Whether or not that is a problem is only Eclipse's opinion, of course.

Comment: Agreed, must be an eclipse issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking the var statement into multiple var statements:
var inputs;
var index;
var inputLenght;

Might be a Eclipse javascript warning issue (not understanding var statement declaring multiple vars...

Comment: var inputLength;
var inputs;
var index;
OR this var inputs, index, inputLength; ==== > same , i still have the warning.